# How do I make my rigid body rotate a fixed angle value each time I click the movement keys

Tags: unity, c#

Ive tried some experiments with the character rotation, but I dont want it to rotate when he touches something, but I also need to unfreeze the Z axis rotation or else the character doesnt rotate when I press a key. My code is this right now, each time I press play (with the Z axis unfreeze) the character just turns like 10 degrees each time I press a key and he is still interacting with objetcs, I dunno what I can do and I might need some help :/

```
public float speed = 2f;
private Rigidbody rb;
private float midJump = 1;
private Rigidbody rB;

//Character Movement

void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}
void Update()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");


    Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0f, moveVertical);


    rb.AddForce(movement * speed);


//Character Jump


    if (midJump == 1 && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector3(0, 45, 0);
        midJump = 2;
    }


//Character Rotation

    else if (rb.velocity.y == 0.0)
        midJump = 1;

    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
            rb.AddRelativeTorque(new Vector3(0, 0, 90));
        rb.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
            rb.AddRelativeTorque(new Vector3(0, 0, -90));
        rb.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
            rb.AddRelativeTorque(new Vector3(0, 0, 180));
        rb.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
            rb.AddRelativeTorque(new Vector3(0, 0, 0));
        rb.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
    }








}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want your player's rotation to be affected by physics collisions, then freeze the Z-axis rotation and use one of these properties/functions which change the direction directly instead of indirectly through torgue:

- [`rb.rotation = quaternion`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-rotation.html)
- [`Rigidbody.MoveRotation(quaternion)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MoveRotation.html)
- [`Transform.rotation = quaternion`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-rotation.html)
- [`Transform.Rotate(angles)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html)

All these different ways do basically the same thing, but have subtle differences. For more information about what these differences are and whether or not they are relevant to your particular game, check out the relevant documentation behind the links.

Comment: The MoveRotation method is good for this too.

Comment: @DMGregory Before we start a nitpicking war about all the other alternatives, I just listed all I could think of.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend the latter two you've added, since manipulating a rigidbody's transform directly can subtly break certain physics behaviours like interpolation, or cause collisions to misbehave.

Comment: I found a solution thanks everyone, now I just need to understand how to make the turn smooth

Comment: @HugoSousa If this answer answered your question, please accept it by clicking the checkmark-icon next to it. If it didn't and you solved your problem differently, please post an own answer so others can benefit from your experience. If you want to know how to smooth your turning, please post a new question about that where you show your code, explain how the rotations made by that code look and how you would like them to look instead.